# how to call partial view from other partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

partial view navbar :

```
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Login","Home")" class="nav-link">
      <span class="sidenav-mini-icon"> L </span>
      <span class="sidenav-normal"> Login </span>
    </a>
 </li>
```

HomeController :

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
   return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_login.cshtml");
}
```

but after running, an error appears :

**The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Requested URL: /Home/Login**

why doesn't it appear and why does the url request go to Home/Login instead of the partialview?

Answer (score 1):

Just right folder name and '/' partial view name

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
   return PartialView("Shared/_login");
   //or
   return PartialView("Shared/_login", model if any);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

changed result to ParsialViewResult or change it return View()